# Join Two Columns and display in Single

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL Query which display two columns separately.

I wanted to display two columns result set to be as one column.

Let's consider the Employees table in the Northwind database where I want to display the First Name and Last Name as simply as Name.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: sorry sir, i do not know how to post. please refer northwind db -> employees table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL uses CONCAT for Concatenating two columns. 
For the case of Employees table in Northwind database, try the following query.

```
SELECT CONCAT (emp.first_name,emp.last_name) AS CustName FROM employees emp;
```

I think the above query will do the needful. This question is the possible duplicate otherwise.

You could use the following for further references.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Comment: thanks it worked like !

Answer (score 2):

The [`concat_ws`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function is just what you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name)
FROM   employees
```

Comment: @XING OP is using [tag:mysql]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, " ", LastName) as Name FROM Northwind
```

You can use CONCAT function in mysql to do this.